# Retrieve local administrators on user login then write to network share

Tags: windows, permissions, group-policy

I've been given a problem that is outside of my wheelhouse and I'm not sure the best way to address it.  The problem I'm trying to address is twofold:

1. Remove accounts with administrator permissions that have no justification.
2. Strip administrator permissions from user-level accounts.

I want to run a PowerShell script at logon, pull the accounts from the Administrators group and save them to a csv on a network drive. I've written the script and tested it locally, it works flawlessly.  However, the share I want to write to is only accessible to the cybersecurity team. I believe that if I run the script as the NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM account I'll also be able to write to the network share w/o issue.

So, my questions:

1. Do I need to set this script up as a GPO script to ensure it uses the right account?
2. Am I correct that NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM will be able to pull the accounts I want and write to the network share?
3. Is there another way to do this that I'm not considering?

Comment: Why script it? This is exactly what [Restricted Groups](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20402.active-directory-group-policy-restricted-groups.aspx) is designed to do.

Comment: I'd never heard of Restricted Groups, thanks for the link! I think these are perfect once we clean up what we have out there.  Because of poor acct management in the past we have hundreds of admin accounts out there that may/may not be necessary.  Part of this project is to demonstrate how bad our environment is, not just clean it up, which is why I would like to script it and pull all the accounts from as many machines as I can.  But, this is an unknown area for me so I may be going about it wrong, and appreciate any/all guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Item 1 - I think I understand your question. Are you asking about a script defined in a GPO vs a script defined in the user's login script field in AD? Then you're on the right track but a little wrong. A GPO login script defined in User Configuration (or an AD user login script) runs as the user - it runs at login for that user, so it runs as the user. A machine startup script, defined in a Computer Configuration GPO, will run as the local workstation's NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM account.

Item 2 - not correct, NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM only has rights on the local system it's running on - in your scenario, that's the workstation. That account will have no rights to the network share. If you're running as a startup script, thus as SYSTEM, you could allow GUEST to be able to write to that share and folder but not read. If you're running as a login script, you could allow "Domain Users" to write but not read.

In either scenario, as long as each instance of the script is writing to a CSV that's unique, perhaps the name of the workstation it's running on, possibly concatenated with the date-and-timestamp, you should be good.

Item 3 - as JScott said, you can define this in Restricted Groups, rather than manually investigate and remediate. It's better to define what you want in policy than apply band-aids.

**EDIT:**

Item 3 option 2 - write or find a function to connect remotely to a Windows machine and dump the members (recursively) of the local Administrators group. Create an array of all machines in your domain. As an account with admin privileges, on a machine with access to all machines, run that function against the array, perhaps with some smart checking/logging of machines that aren't reachable so you can run again against those and/or cleanup your AD if there's stale machines. Export the output to your CSV files.

Comment: Concerning Restricted Groups, I think they are a good next step.  For the moment we have hundreds of admin-level accounts and no way to know if they are justified w/o investigating them - Hence the desire to dump all accounts into a central place. With Restricted Groups, once the policy is refreshed, those accounts not in the restricted group gets wiped out, yes?  If so, I don't think that's a risk my CISO is willing to accept right now.

Comment: OK, wrote you another approach, Item 3 option 2